# How to set Height of ComboBox Autocomplete of Material UI using ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Was trying to set the height of the component (input) with no successes, any idea how to to the trick?

here is the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dkicr?file=/demo.js

Comment: The height of the input?

Comment: Yep, will update the post, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that you are talking about the height of the element that contains the list of options - you can use the `ListboxProps` property of the `Autocomplete` to set the properties of the Listbox.

From there you can set the style of the container:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
  ListboxProps={
    {
      style:{
          maxHeight: '150px',
          border: '1px solid red'
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

> Note the `maxHeight` (and not `height`) because you don't want to set the height to be larger if you have only 1 option to show.

Comment: Hello! thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for the size of the actual input not the drop-down, any idea on how to tweak it?

Comment: The input is your `TextField`, can you explain what is the issue with setting the style on that element?

Comment: Yep - was adding that to the element next to width:300 but it didn't work..

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jRO6.png ?

Comment: Yes! actually the other way around, I would like to make the height smaller than the original size

Comment: Thanks for the Example using ListboxProps, that helped me very much right now